# Change icon when focus and unfocus Android Tab widget

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, android-layout

Hey I'd like to change the icon from the TabWidget on Android by focusing and unfocusing the tab. I mean, when I select the Tab, the icon shows for example green, and when I select the oter tab, the icon changes to red.

I'm calling a unique icon this way:

```
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("one").setIndicator("Rated Calls", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ratedcallicon))
```

How to make it change the image of the icon when I select other tab?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every drawable has the ability to take up multiple images based on its current state (see how it has a `setState` member. You could use `StateListDrawable`, or even specify the states in XML.

There is a state for "focused", and FWIK that works on tabs.

Comment: This is the way to go, this link should be helpful http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: Thanks schwiz! I had been looking for that link.

Comment: I followed the tutorial that @schwiz posted. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Those multi-state drawables are awesome. You can have lots of fun with them :)